# Form validation: Click Submit not Trigger Validations

Tags: jquery, html, css

I create validation form by using Jquery (not plus-in).

Problem: 1. I am not fill in any field and click on Submit button, all validations are not triggered and the form is submitted.  I think I don't have a function on the button to trigger the validations.

Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

This is code sample in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgxtv2fL/5/)

JS.

```
$(function () { 
    /* $('#form').submit(function () { */
        $('#firstname').on('input', function() {
        var firstName = $('#firstname').val();
        if (!firstName) {
            $('#firstname').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
            return false;
        }
        else {return true;}
      });
      $('#lasttname').on('input', function() { 
         var lasttName = $('#lastname').val();
         if (!lastName) {
            $('#lasttname').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
            return false;
        }
        else {return true;} 
      });

        $('#phone').on('input', function() {
            var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
            if (number.length == 7) {
            number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2");
            } else if (number.length == 10) {
            number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
            }
            $(this).val(number)
        });
        $('#email').on('input', function() {
            var input=$(this);
            var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
            var is_email=re.test(input.val());
            if(is_email){input.removeClass("alert-on")}
            else{input.addClass("alert-on");}
        });

    });
    $("input").on("change keyup paste", function(){
      $(this).siblings('.error').removeClass('alert-on');
/* }) */
 })
```

HTML

```
<form id="form">
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First name*" id="firstname">
                <div class="error">Required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last name*" id="lastname">
                <div class="error">Required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
                <div class="error">A valid email address is required</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Phone*" maxlength="12" id="phone">
                <div class="error">Required</div>
            </div>

            <div id="form_submit">
                <button type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

CSS

```
input {
  display: list-item;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
.alert-on {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why is `$('#form').submit(function ()` commented?

Comment: The document ready is not closed properly with the commented lines

Comment: `$('#form').submit(function ()` was added, but didn't work out, so I commented.

Comment: @Taplar, the closed commented line is not for `document ready`, it is for `$('#form').submit(function ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling **onchange** and **oninput** at the same time. which add class in your alert label on change and remove it at the same time **onkeyup** event. you need to do something like this

```js
function validateForm() {
    val = true;
    var firstName = $('#firstname').val();
    if (!firstName) {
        $('#firstname').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
        val = false;
    }
    var lastName = $('#lastname').val();
    if (!lastName) {
        $('#lastname').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
        val = false;
    }

    var input = $('#email');
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    var is_email = re.test(input.val());
    if (!is_email) {
        $('#email').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
        val = false;
    }

    return val;
}
$(function () {
    $("input").on("change keyup paste", function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) { $(this).siblings('.error').addClass('alert-on'); }
        else { $(this).siblings('.error').removeClass('alert-on'); }
    });
    $("#form").submit(function (event) {
        if (validateForm()) {
            return;
        };
        event.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

```css
input {
  display: list-item;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
.alert-on {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="action.php" method="post">
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First name*" id="firstname">
                <div class="error">Required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last name*" id="lastname">
                <div class="error">Required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
              <div class="error">A valid email address is required</div> 
            </div>
           
        
            <div id="form_submit">
                <button type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Zulqarnain Jalil for your help and thanks for pointing out what was my mistake!  Your code works so well.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        input {
            display: list-item;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .error {
            display: none;
            color: red;
        }

        .alert-on {
            display: block;
        }
    </style> </head>

<body>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="onSubmit(event)">
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First name*" id="firstname" onblur="onChangeFirstName()">
            <div class="error">Required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last name*" id="lastname" onblur="onChangeLastName()">
            <div class="error">Required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" onblur="onChangeEmail()">
            <div class="error">A valid email address is required</div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone*" maxlength="12" id="phone" onblur="onChangePhone()">
            <div class="error">Required</div>
        </div>

        <div id="form_submit">
            <button type="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onChangeFirstName() {
            var firstName = $('#firstname').val();
            if (firstName.trim() == "") {
                $('#firstname').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function onChangeLastName() {
            var lastName = $('#lastname').val();
            if (lastName.trim() == "") {
                $('#lastname').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function onChangePhone() {
            var number = $("#phone").val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
            if (number.length == 7) {
                number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2");
            } else if (number.length == 10) {
                number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
            }
            $("#phone").val(number)
        }

        function onChangeEmail() {
            var input = $("#email");
            var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
            var is_email = re.test(input.val());
            if (is_email) {
                $('#email').siblings(".error").removeClass('alert-on');
                return true;
            } else {
                $('#email').siblings(".error").addClass('alert-on');
                return false;
            }
        }

        function onSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (onChangeFirstName() && onChangeLastName() && onChangeEmail()) {
                $("#form").submit();
            }
        }
    </script> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you zcionn!  It works well, but I wonder if all validations of all fields trigger at the time if we didn't fill in any instead of one validation at a time. https://jsfiddle.net/2tdLkznp/

Comment: i did an AND in onSubmit so if it encounters a false it stops. you can change it to run all the other functions and just check if all of them returns true then you proceed with submit

Comment: like 

var fname = onChangeFirstName();
var lname = onChangeLastName();
var email = onChangeEmail();

if (fname && lname && email) {
                $("#form").submit();
}